# ActionScript 3: Resizing image inside UIComponent

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a UIComponent and inside it I put a loader (which loads an image file).

THE PROBLEM:
Even though I resize the UIComponent(to a square), it will still follow the size of the image in the loader. But when I resize the image in the loader, it will become stretched. What I want to do is have a container(UIComponent) that has a fixed square size and after the image has been loaded it will just fit in the dimention of the container without being stretched. Can anyone help me how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've long been using this function to resize an image while preserving the aspect ratio:

```
public function constraintResize(iSourceWidth:*, iSourceHeight:*, iTargetWidth:*, iTargetHeight:*, iFitSmallerDimension:*):* {
  if (iFitSmallerDimension == undefined) iFitSmallerDimension = false;
  if (iTargetWidth == 0 || iTargetHeight == 0) return;
  if (iSourceWidth == 0 || iSourceHeight == 0) return;

  var newWidth:*;
  var newHeight:*;
  var targetRatio:*;
  var sourceRatio:*;

  var output:* = { width:iSourceWidth, height:iSourceHeight };

  if (iSourceWidth <= iTargetWidth && iSourceHeight <= iTargetHeight) {
    if (iFitSmallerDimension) {
      targetRatio = iTargetWidth / iTargetHeight;
      sourceRatio = iSourceWidth / iSourceHeight;
      if (sourceRatio < targetRatio) {
        newHeight = iTargetHeight;
        newWidth = newHeight * sourceRatio;
      } else {
        newWidth = iTargetWidth;
        newHeight = newWidth / sourceRatio;
      } 
      output.width = newWidth
      output.height = newHeight
    }

    } else {

    targetRatio = iTargetWidth / iTargetHeight
    sourceRatio = iSourceWidth / iSourceHeight
    if (sourceRatio < targetRatio) {
      newHeight = iTargetHeight
      newWidth = newHeight * sourceRatio
    } else {
      newWidth = iTargetWidth
      newHeight = newWidth / sourceRatio
    }

    output.width = newWidth
    output.height = newHeight
  }

  return output
}
```

The function will give you the ideal dimensions to fit `source` within `target`. So, in your case, you can use it that way:

```
var s:* = constraintResize(loader.contentWidth, loader.contentHeight, yourSquare.width, yourSquare.height);
loader.width = s.width;
loader.height = s.height;
```

Comment: whoah! I thought i can do it in within 5 lines of codes. THANK YOU for this! I will try this definitely!

Answer (score 1):

use UILoader component and set scaleContent=true in component inspector wondow.

Comment: i am trying to import fl.containers.UILoader but flex doesnt seem to understand this package.... do i need some special library for this?

Comment: sorry i don't have enough knowledge of flex.